# Cakephp package manager (Installer setup like wordpress and joomla) framework

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I was wondering, is there any package manager which i can automatically setup my local Cakephp project to another computer where the user has Installer page and install creates and installs the database frontend(in HTML page), I appreciate your suggestions thank you. Any package or script or process which I can flow to make setup process like this one
https://packagist.org/packages/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want something that will download the code for your project, or a web-based front end for entering database parameters, or both.

Comment: @GregSchmidt webfront for entering database parameters installer for project

Comment: I've used [this plugin](https://github.com/anuj9196/CakePHP-App-Installer) for a project, and added a few features to it. Might be helpful for you?